# Set $PSDefaultParametersValues for use within Module Scope

Tags: powershell, module, scope, default-value

I guess I'm just missing something, but here is my set up, i have a test module with three test functions, i want to set the $PSDefaultParameterValues to make a common parameter value that only exists to the other cmdlets in said module.  Here is my code:

test.psm1:

```
$PSDefaultParameterValues.Clear()

"$(Split-Path -Path $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path)\*.ps1" | Resolve-Path | % { . $_.ProviderPath }
```

in the same dir i have my functions:

New-TestFunction.ps1:

```
Function New-TestFunction
{
     [CmdletBinding()]
     [OutputType([String])]

     Param
     (
         [String]
         $InputString
     )

     $Script:PSDefaultParameterValues.Add("Write-TestValue:OutputValue", $InputString)
}
```

Write-TestValue.ps1:

```
Function Write-TestValue
{
     [CmdletBinding()]
     [OutputType()]

     Param
     (
          [Parameter()]
          [String]
          $OutputValue
     )

     Write-Output -InputObject $OutputValue
}
```

so, i should be able to do this:

```
PS C:\> New-TestFunction -InputString 'Test String'; Write-TestValue
PS C:\> 'Test String'
```

But it returns nothing, the $OutputValue remains $null.  The only way i have gotten it to work is by using the $Global: scope, which i would rather not do.  I feel like functions imported in under the Module scope should see the $Script: Scope of variables.  I wrote a little test function:

Write-ScriptPSDefaultParameterValues.ps1

```
Function Write-ScriptPSDefaultParameterValues
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    [OutputType()]

    Param
    (
    )

    Write-Output -InputObject $Script:PSDefaultParameterValues
}
```

And this works:

```
PS C:\>  New-TestFunction -InputString 'Test String'; Write-ScriptPSDefaultParameterValues
Name                         Value
----                         -----
Write-TestValue:OutputValue  Test String
```

So from within side the functions, the $Script scope exists, just not in the parameters.  Maybe i just don't understand how the scopes work completely,  thanks for any help and/or clarification.

Answer (score 5):

`$PSDefaultParameterValues` get read from scope where invocation occurs, not from scope where function defined.

```powershell
New-Module {
    $PSDefaultParameterValues=@{'F:Value'=10}
    function F{
        [CmdletBinding()]
        param(
            $Value
        )
        "F:`$Value:$Value"
    }
    function G{
        [CmdletBinding()]
        param(
            $Value
        )
        "G:`$Value:$Value"
    }
    function Invoke-F{
        F
    }
    function Invoke-G{
        G
    }
}|Out-Null
$PSDefaultParameterValues=@{'G:Value'=20}
F
G
Invoke-F
Invoke-G
```

Results:

```
F:$Value:
G:$Value:20
F:$Value:10
G:$Value:
```

So, when function executed from global scope, then global `$PSDefaultParameterValues` get read. And when function executed from other module function, then module `$PSDefaultParameterValues` get read.

Comment: Thank you for the great explination, now let me ask you this, Would it be that bad if i use the $Global: Scope?  99% of the time, i would never do it, however, this goes back to a module I'm working on https://github.com/dotps1/WinSCP and basically, the first thing that has to be done, is create a Session object, then that is used by every other cmdlet, So, my code would look like this:  `$Global:PSDefaultParameterValues["*-WinSCP*:WinSCPSession"] = $session`.  I would think that would not affect any other cmdlets.  Thanks again.

Comment: @dotps1 IMHO, it is better to allow user to set `$PSDefaultParameterValues` by h(im|er)self, If (s)he want to do that. Main problem, as I see, with your code is, that someone can import your module with custom prefix `Import-Module -Prefix custom`. And your default parameters would not work.

Comment: One workaround I tend to use: Write Get-WinSCPConfig and Set-WinSCPConfig functions that store a script scope variable, and optionally serialize to disk for persistent 'defaults'.  Use these as default values for appropriate function parameters.  Poorly implemented examples [here](https://github.com/RamblingCookieMonster/Infoblox).  Cheers!